# How to generate multiplication tables up to nxn?

Tags: list-manipulation, syntax, algebra, arithmetic

I'm doing a simple multiplication table and I have this that I'm having a hard time with.
I imagine that there must be a shorter way to do it, what I can't get is that it paints black the first column on the left and the main diagonal where the squares of the numbers are.
help me a little

```
Insert[Insert[
Grid[Table[i*j, {i, 1, 10}, {j, 1, 10}]], {Dividers -> All, 
Spacings -> 1.5 {1, 1}}, 
 2]                                   , {Background -> {None, 
 { GrayLevel[0.7], {White}}}, Dividers -> {Black, {All -> Black}}, 
Frame -> True, Spacings -> {3, {3, {0.7}, 3}}}, 3]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Grid[
 Table[i*j, {i, 1, 10}, {j, 1, 10}],
 Frame -> All, 
 Background -> {{1 -> LightGray}, 
   None, ({#, #} -> LightGray & /@ Range[10])}]
```

[image]

Or perhaps

```
Grid[
 Table[i*j, {i, 1, 10}, {j, 1, 10}],
 Frame -> All, 
 Background -> {{1 -> LightGray}, {1 -> 
     LightGray}, ({#, #} -> LightBlue & /@ Range[10])}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat simpler would be to use TableForm. One possibility:

```
TableForm[Table[i*j, {i, 2, 10}, {j, 2, 10}], TableHeadings -> {Range[10], Range[10]}]
```